# How to get tv show episode and session number from title

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm try to get tvhsow season and episode number from the title

I try following code which works but it also picking up title like xxxxe 3 as episode 3

```
$episode = $title | Select-String -Pattern "E(\d+)", "E (\d+)", "Episode (\d+)" | % {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
$season = $title | Select-String -Pattern "S(\d+)", "S (\d+)", "Season (\d+)" | % {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

How to i make sure that I can pick up the season number and episode from any of these formats.

- xxx S01E01
- xxxe 1 S01E01
- xxx S01 E01
- xxx 01x01
- xxx Season 01 Episode 01

If above seaon or episode numbers are not in the title of the show then I just want to return nothing e.g. if the show is named as "xxxxxE 1"

Comment: Adding new requirements **after** the question has been answered is considered a bad habit. Since you have received two answers already, you start adding new filename examples that were (and are still) **not** mentioned in the question, so nobody could have created a regex to deal with those also. What do you expect to get here, a _Universal_ regex that will parse out everything you ever throw at it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following

1. Seasons and episodes will always be 2 (or more) numbers
2. Seasons and episodes will always be at the end of the filename.

I would recommend anchoring to the end of the name with the regex pattern. From there we account for 0 or more characters before a period (file extension), 1 literal period (for the extension), 0 or more characters between the period and the episode, and 0 or more characters between the season and the episode.

```
$examples = @'
xxx S01E02.avi
xxxe 1 S02E03.mp3
xxx S03 E04.mov
xxx 04x05.png
xxx Season 05 Episode 06.wav
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$examples | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '.+(\d{2,}).*(\d{2,}).*\..*$'){
        "Season: {0}  Episode: {1}" -f $matches.1,$matches.2
    }
}
```

This will output

```
Season: 01  Episode: 02
Season: 02  Episode: 03
Season: 03  Episode: 04
Season: 04  Episode: 05
Season: 05  Episode: 06
```

You didn't show how you populated $title, so it was assumed to just be a string. However if you wanted to apply to file objects, you have a couple of options.

We can leave the regex pattern alone and use the Name property.

```
$videolist = Get-Childitem -Path path\to\movies -Filter *.whatever

foreach($video in $videolist){
    if($video.Name -match '.+(\d{2,}).*(\d{2,}).*\..*$'){
        "Season: {0}  Episode: {1}" -f $matches.1,$matches.2
    }
}
```

or

We can use the BaseName property and adjust the regex slightly.

```
$videolist = Get-Childitem -Path path\to\movies -Filter *.whatever

foreach($video in $videolist){
    if($video.BaseName -match '.+(\d{2,}).*(\d{2,}).*$'){
        "Season: {0}  Episode: {1}" -f $matches.1,$matches.2
    }
}
```

Comment: I modify your code but it didnt work. can you check and let me know what i'm doing wrong

$examples = 'xxx S01 E01'

if($examples -match '.+(\d{2,}).*(\d{2,}).*\..*$'){
    $season = $matches.1
    $episode = $matches.2
}

Comment: There is no dot at the end in your example. So you need to remove the literal dot from the regex `'.+(\d{2,}).*(\d{2,}).*$'`

Comment: Thank you that has worked but if its S1E05 it doesnt pick up the season number and also if the title is like xxxxxxxx S10 E06 xxxxx 01 05 it picks the last digit. Is they any way I can provide values e.g. S01 E01,S01E01, S1E05,01x05, Season 1 Episode 5

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a regex string that parses out the season and episode numbers like this:

```
$examples = 'xxx S01E01','xxxe 1 S01E03','xxx S06 E01','xxx 01x01','xxx Season 01 Episode 02'

foreach ($title in $examples) {
    if ($title -match '(?:(?:S(?:eason)?)?\s*(\d+)[\sx]*)(?:(?:E(?:pisode)?)?\s*(\d+))') {
        $season  = [int]$matches[1]
        $episode = [int]$matches[2]

        # just to display the output:
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Title   = $title
            Season  = $season
            Episode = $episode
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Title                    Season Episode
-----                    ------ -------
xxx S01E01                    1       1
xxxe 1 S01E03                 1       3
xxx S06 E01                   6       1
xxx 01x01                     1       1
xxx Season 01 Episode 02      1       2
```

Regex details:

```
(?:                # Match the regular expression below
   (?:             # Match the regular expression below
      S            # Match the character “S” literally
      (?:          # Match the regular expression below
         eason     # Match the characters “eason” literally
      )?           # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )?              # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \s              # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      *            # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (               # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
      \d           # Match a single digit 0..9
         +         # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )
   [\sx]           # Match a single character present in the list below
                   # A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
                   # The character “x”
      ?            # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(?:                # Match the regular expression below
   (?:             # Match the regular expression below
      E            # Match the character “E” literally
      (?:          # Match the regular expression below
         pisode    # Match the characters “pisode” literally
      )?           # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )?              # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \s              # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      *            # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (               # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      \d           # Match a single digit 0..9
         +         # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )
)
```

<sup>I have changed some of your examples to make it clearer the numbers are correctly found</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the code but its doing same as before
Title   Season Episode
-----   ------ -------
xxxE 01      0       1

Comment: If the title has something like this xxxxE01 or xxxE 01 it still thing its episode number. I need to make sure it only register season number or episode if its in following format. (see my post)

Comment: @maj you should explain then what that `e` attached to the `xxx` means as the example also has a clear Season and Episode code after it,

Comment: The xxxe 01 is the name of the show and not the episode number the season or episode number will be in this order. S01 E01, S01E01, 01X01, Season 01 Episode 01

Comment: For example I have an TV show called E2 Part 1 without anything else, so the script should return nothing as it doesnt match the following format S01 E01, S01E01, 01X01, Season 01 Episode 01

Comment: @maj No, it parses correctly. If I for instance use a title like `'xxxe 1 S07E03'`, the result is `Season: 7  Episode: 3`. It doesn't look at the `e` that happens to be the last character of the title in the filename. As for the filename you now mention in your comment: `E2 Part 1`, you did **not** put a name like that in your question, so the only formats we can use is what **you** showed us. BTW, my code also correctly skips a filename like that. Have you even tried it?

Comment: I tried the code but it still picked the season and episode number. Can you pelase try it your pc. give then title as xxxxE 01 xxxx. it should return false as it doesnt match the format

Comment: What I mean that if the title is as "xxxx xxxxxE 1" it still picks up Episode 01 as you can see I havent put any season or episode number in the title

Comment: "xxxx xxxxxE 1"  is full name of the show the title doesnt have any other information. If any title ends with xxxS 1 or xxxE 1 then it should still return false as it doesnt match my format.  I have updated the question

Comment: @maj If you try a filename `"xxxx xxxxxE 1"`, there won't be any output, because the regex **doesn't match** and it will certainly **not** _"still pick up Episode 01"_, . Just try it, add `'xxxx xxxxxE 1'` in the array of examples and you will not see output on that one.

Comment: Sorry if you have 01 then picks up 0 as season number and 1 as episode number. I was trying with following file name "xxxx xxxxxE 01", if any of the file ends with 2 digit it picks up first number as season and 2nd as episode. If I havent provide season or episode as S01E01, S01 E01, 01x01, episode 01 season 01 then i would like the script to return false